# File Sizes Go Up When I Remove Background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, file-format, jpg, file-size

I have these `.jpg` pics and I removed their background. But after I saved them to `.png` their file sizes skyrocketed. Like a `198kb` file becomes `3.82mb` after I save it to `.png`. Why is that?

Comment: PNG: uses a lossless compression JPG: lossy compression

Answer (score 2):

JPG uses much worse compression settings (worse for quality, better for size)

When you save a photo as a `.jpg` it's heavily compressed (and blurred out too) which is why you have a much smaller file size.

---

See this excellent [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/54551/63979) by Vincent on this. Also have a look at the main question and other answers, great info!

There's also an awesome [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7752936/9240845) on Stack Overflow about this.